# HTML: put an image between halfway and right side of the screen

Tags: html

I'm trying to place an image around halfway between the middle of the screen and all the way on the right side (which is where it is right now).

The HTML code:

```
<img src="jeremy.png" alt="Jeremy Smith" width="100" height="100" style="float:right">
```

Is there any way to float the image in 3/4 of the way to the right? Or something like that?

Comment: You could use a right margin that pulls it away from the right side...

Comment: btw:  float:right makes elements float the the right of other elements.  It's not an alignment thing,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few ways this could be accomplished. One easy way I could think of is to use a div to align it in the right region of the screen. You could also position the image absolute or apply the margin to the image.

```
div {
  margin-left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

<div><img src="jeremy.png"><\div>
```

Comment: Sorry typo in above closing div (I'm on my phone, sorry). Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xwk61z40/

Answer (score 2):

```
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 75%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

Margin and translate are your best friends for positioning. Since translate is self-referential, using `transform: translate(-50%, 0)` causes the margin to be offset from the center of the image, rather than the left edge. This should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious way is to use:

```
#imgAtThreeQuarters {
  /* positioning the element in relation to 
     its closest offset-parent element: */
  position: absolute;

  /* positioning the left-border of the
     image 75% from the left-most border
     of its closest offset-parent element: */
  left: 75%;

  /* moving the image to the left by half
     of its width, to position the horizontal
     center of the image at 75% of the
     offset-parent's width: */
  margin-left: -50px;
}
```

```css
#imgAtThreeQuarters {
  position: absolute;
  left: 75%;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<img id="imgAtThreeQuarters" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature" />
```

This requires that its offset-parent (either the `<body>` element, or the closest ancestor with a `position` attribute-value of other than `static`) has a width of `100%` of the page.

Also, of course, I've used non-inline CSS, so to use the above the image would need to have a corresponding `id` property.